# Javascript based trigger for angularjs popover/tooltip

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

Here's what I am trying to do:

I have a grid of elements that have text-overflow: hidden and I want to be able to show a popover/tooltip iff the text is actually hidden. I can do this manually with javascript by doing some width math but I am unsure how I would modify the existing directives to add this new condition.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show the existing directive and what you have tried.

Comment: I don't really have anything yet, I'm just in the process of researching this framework for a project and wasn't having any luck googling for the solution. I was hoping something like this might have already been built but that might not be the case.